# Web.config transfor is adding &#xD;&#xA; How to ignore linebreak during transformation

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, web.config-transform, slowcheetah

In my ASP.net web.config I have below configuration

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
       <add name="Content-Security-Policy-report-only" value="default-src 'none';
            script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' script1;
            img-src 'self' img1;
            style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' css1;
            font-src 'self' url2;
            connect-src 'self' url1;
            frame-src 'self';
            report-uri value1" />
     </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

In web.dev.config I don't have any transformations related to this XML path. but after transformation, I could see **`&#xD;&#xA;`** on every line breaks.
How to fix this issue?

After transformation output will be like

```
 <add name="Content-Security-Policy-report-only" value="default-src 'none';&#xD;&#xA;   script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' script1;&#xD;&#xA;  img-src 'self' img1;&#xD;&#xA;  style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' css1;&#xD;&#xA;    font-src 'self' url2;&#xD;&#xA; connect-src 'self' url1;&#xD;&#xA;  frame-src 'self';&#xD;&#xA; report-uri value1" />
```

Comment: I would suggest not putting line breaks in the source xml. Typically this doesn't change very often, if you need to change it, copy the text into an editor with line wrap, edit it and copy it back